# Location Services permission is empty

Tags: ios, permissions, mapkit, geofencing, location-services

I'm using Location Manager to track regions. On one device my app behaves strange. Location permission was granted to be used Always, but Location Manager returns 0,0 as current coordinate and when I go to the Settings / Privacy / Location Services / App - neither Never or Always are selected.
This happens on iOS 11.0.2

I've set plist key (NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription) and use only requestAlwaysAuthorization because it's required to region monitoring.

One important thing - Google Maps and Apple Maps use current location normally.

Comment: try adding this in .plist file 
   `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Location When In Use Usage Description</string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brad Jensen explains in the WWDC talk, Apple has decided that forcing the user to give the app “Always” location access is a bad user experience:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/713/

So when you build your app using the iOS 11 SDK, you are now required to provide an `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in all cases (if you use location at all). For “Always” access, you can additionally provide a second key, which is now called `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`.